# NuxtJs Scroll Behavior issue

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a couple of issues with scroll behavior in my Nuxt application. I have 3 pages `Home`, `Individual posts` and `category` page

1. When I am moving from `home page` to the `individual posts page` there is a scroll transition from the bottom to the top of the page, what I am trying to achieve is when I switch to the individual page, the scroll bar should be default at the top and not the scroll animation.
2. When I click the back button from the `Individual posts page` it's not taking me to the saved Position of the `Home Page`.
3. When I am on the `category1` page, If I scroll a little down and click on `2nd category`, Again I am seeing the bottom to top page scroll issue. Ideally, it should default to the top when we switch pages (I am using `asyncdata` this I've tested with fetch method, with fetch it works perfectly )
4. If I click the back button from `category2` it takes me to the saved position of `category1` page which is correct but again I am seeing top to bottom scroll behavior, it should go to the saved position Instantly without any scroll animation.
5. If I click `Individual post` link from the `category page` and click back button from the `Individual page`,it's not taking me to the saved Position of the `category page` (scroll is getting stuck in between)

Its really hard for me to explain this, [this is a 30 second video link](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c3hhqHVYPcG), for better understanding.

I have tried `scrollToTop` and tried to modify default scroll behavior.

```
export default function (to, from, savedPosition) {
  if (savedPosition) {
    return savedPosition
  }
  return { x: 0, y: 0 }
}
```

This is my [Git repo link](https://github.com/shanks25/nuxt-scroll-demo) for this Nuxt project.
Please Guide. Thanks

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure if this part of the code is relevant, it's probably the rest which is the culprit. Do you mind creating a [repro] for overall faster debugging? Also, did you checked the value of `savedPosition` at several stages? It's maybe containing a value that you do not expect. Otherwise, I still recommend looking at some of my [previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+scroll) regarding this specific topic.

Comment: Hi,I checked the values of ```savedPosition``` , values looks correct to me, I am not sure what is causing the issue maybe the asyncData call, CSS or the component , and its on couple of pages, so it is little confusing what minimal reproducible example to share. So I created simple 3 page nuxt project (clone of original one) and shared the 
[Github Link](https://github.com/shanks25/nuxt-scroll-demo)  in the question. I checked the previous answers as well.

Comment: So, what do you want exactly? Go back to the top every time? Or do not have a transition on specific paths? There is quite a lot of text here and it's hard to follow without simpler bullet points of the final result that you expect.

Comment: Yes only two things, 1) I want to go to the top every time a new page is opened without any bottom to top scroll transition, 2) and when I click browser back button, go to the saved position instantly without top to bottom scroll transition

Comment: So, if the user clicks "◀️" on his browser, keep the scroll position but if he clicks on the `Back` button, you want to scroll up to the top? So, differentiate both actions? Hm, it would maybe be possible with a hack of some sort...

Comment: sorry its opposite of that, If users clicks on ```<nuxt-link>```  go to the top of the page and when click browser back button or ```<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="$router.go(-1)"> Back</button>``` go to the saved position of previous page. that's all, all this without any bottom to top or top to bottom scroll transition.

Comment: @KunalRajput did you find a solution, I have the exact same problem. 
For anyone who want to see the problem, see here: https://jbe-nuxt.test.boriskamp.nl/ scroll down to an event and press the 'info' button and you will see the page scrolls up and then transitions to the next page.